# Trove Guest Agent Not starting

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-juno

I am trying to install Openstack Trove guestagent, however, it's unable to start and giving me the following error (as observed by the logs):

```
2015-04-17 17:54:45.181 3237 CRITICAL root [-] RuntimeError: Manager class not registered for datastore manager None 
2015-04-17 17:54:45.181 3237 TRACE root Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-04-17 17:54:45.181 3237 TRACE root   File "/usr/bin/trove-guestagent", line 10, in <module>
2015-04-17 17:54:45.181 3237 TRACE root     sys.exit(main())
2015-04-17 17:54:45.181 3237 TRACE root   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trove/cmd/guest.py", line 58, in main
2015-04-17 17:54:45.181 3237 TRACE root     raise RuntimeError(msg)
2015-04-17 17:54:45.181 3237 TRACE root RuntimeError: Manager class not registered for datastore manager None
```

I am unable to understand what's the issue. Any guidance would be very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Trove (test code), I've found [this line](https://github.com/openstack/trove/blob/master/trove/guestagent/datastore/mysql/service.py#L55):

```
MANAGER = CONF.datastore_manager if CONF.datastore_manager else 'mysql'
```

Try add the following configuration line in your trove-guestagent.conf:

```
datastore_manager = mysql
```

and restart guest agent service.